# Android - Getting Android ID of Android Wearable Device from Smart Phone

Tags: android, wear-os

Is there a way to get the Android ID of an Android Wearable device that pairs with my smart phone?  I have my app running on the smart phone but no app running on the android wearable device (watch for example).

From my understanding, the Android Wearable device and the smart phone will pair via BlueTooth.  I looked through all of the bluetooth APIs (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) and the closest thing I can get to an ID is the UUID which isn't the Android ID (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getUuids())

Thanks!
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible. You need to use the `NodeApi` on the Handheld, to get the connected nodes, through `getConnectedNodes`. It returns an instance of `NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult`. Through this object you can retrieve the list of all the connected nodes. E.g

```
Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult getConnectedNodesResult) {
                for (Node node : getConnectedNodesResult.getNodes()) {
                   Log.i(LOG_TAG, "node id " + node.getId());
                }
         }
});
```

Comment: I know I already approved this answer but I just tested it on a wear emulator and I get this "9e9db081" which seems a bit too short for an Android ID :(  Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Give node.geName() a try

Comment: Thanks -- actually, for some reason, getName and getId return the same values.

Comment: on real devices the id is much longer. It's probably the emulator.